# How to align input text box properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image]

Please see my code, I am trying to build average calculator using HTML, CSS, Bootstrap and Javascript.

The issue is input text box's alignment is not proper; how can I do it in proper way?

User should type first-4th purchase quantity and price and at the end when he clicks on calculate, they should get the average buying price of all quantities together.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doadd() 
    {
        var no1= document.getElementById('txtno1');
        var no2= document.getElementById('txtno2');
        var no3= document.getElementById('txtno3');
        var no4= document.getElementById('txtno4');
        var no5= document.getElementById('txtno5');
        var no6= document.getElementById('txtno6');
        var no7= document.getElementById('txtno7');
        var no8= document.getElementById('txtno8');
        var result=document.getElementById('txtresult');
        var A =Number(no1.value)*Number(no2.value);
        var B =Number(no3.value)*Number(no4.value);
        var C =Number(no5.value)*Number(no6.value);
        var D =Number(no7.value)*Number(no8.value);
        var F =Number(no1.value)+Number(no3.value)+Number(no5.value)+Number(no7.value);
        var E = A+B+C+D;
        result.value = E/F;
        }
    </script>
    <title>Average Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container bg-success text-white">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
    <span class="badge bg-dark"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 text-center fw-bold">
    Average Calculator
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container fst-italic">
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>here,you can calculate the average price of stocks which you bought at different price 
    and quantity.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>Enter 1st Purchase quantity: <input type="text" id='txtno1' ><p/>
    <p>Enter 1st Purchase price   : <input type="text" id='txtno2'></p>
    <p>Enter 2nd Purchase quantity: <input type="text" id='txtno3'></p>
    <p>Enter 2nd Purchase price   : <input type="text" id='txtno4'></p>
    <p>Enter 3rd Purchase quantity: <input type="text" id='txtno5'></p>
    <p>Enter 3rd Purchase price   : <input type="text" id='txtno6'></p>
    <p>Enter 4th Purchase quantity: <input type="text" id='txtno7'></p>
    <p>Enter 4th Purchase price   : <input type="text" id='txtno8'></p>
    <input type="button" id="btnsum" value="Calculte"
    onclick="doadd();">
    <p>Average Buying Price <input type="text" id="txtresult"/></p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

Heading
=======
```

Comment: I would highly recommend using a table as this is tabular data. Alternatively, work with a CSS-Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is tabular data and as such a table would be appropiate even sementaically the right choice.
That table would also drastically reduce the text amount and add readability:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>quantity</th>
    <th>price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1st Purchase</td>
    <td><input type="number" step="1"></td>
    <td><input type="number" step="0.01"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>s
    <td>2nd Purchase</td>
    <td><input type="number" step="1"></td>
    <td><input type="number" step="0.01"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3rd Purchase</td>
    <td><input type="number" step="1"></td>
    <td><input type="number" step="0.01"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4th Purchase</td>
    <td><input type="number" step="1"></td>
    <td><input type="number" step="0.01"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign one row to each label and input field.
For example:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     Enter 1st Purchase quantity:
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="text" id='txtno1' >
    </div>
   </div>
```

And you can follow this for all label and input fields.